# How to implement by viewModels?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I have been trying to implement the LiveData and View Model. In this App, a number is displayed on the screen and we can add five or minus one. Now Earlier I used viewModelProvider but now it is deprecated and I am using "by viewmodels" but it is showing ann error

**fragOne.kt**

```
class fragOne : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentFragoneBinding>(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_fragone,
            container,
            false
        )

        //viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(fragViewModel::class.java)
        // Create the observer which updates the UI.
        val viewModel: fragViewModel by **viewModels()**
        val nameObserver = Observer<Int> {
            viewModel.num.value=it

        }
        // Observe the LiveData, passing in this activity as the LifecycleOwner and the observer.
        viewModel.num.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,nameObserver)
        // setting on Click listener for add button
        binding.add.setOnClickListener()
        {

            //updateNumber()
            viewModel.num.setValue(viewModel.addFive())
        }

        // setting on on Click Listener for minus button
        binding.minus.setOnClickListener()
        {
            viewModel.num.setValue(viewModel.minusOne())
            //updateNumber()
        }


        return binding.root
    }

        // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
}
```

**fragViewModel**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class fragViewModel:ViewModel()
{
    val num: MutableLiveData<Int> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<Int>()
    }
    // Initializing num=0
    init {
         num .value= 0
    }
    // Functions to add five or subtract one

    fun addFive():Int
    {
        var newNumber:Int?=num.value

        return newNumber?.plus(5)?:0
    }

     fun minusOne():Int
    {
        var newNumber:Int?=num.value

        return newNumber?.minus(1)?:0
    }
}
```

In **fragOne** there is an error showing in **by viewModels** . So whats the error.
please let me know if anyone wants the code I will upload it in Github

**build.gradle**

```
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0"
    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"


}
```

Comment: You're asking us "what's the error", but you're the one that can see it, not us. Can you post what the error says? My guess is you're missing the Ktx Fragments dependency in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: and added the dependencies in my question, please tell me what is missing

Comment: You're still missing the **Fragments** Ktx library, which is the one with `by viewModels`. `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.2"`

Comment: I will apply it and let you know

Comment: After I added there was another error showing `cannot inline......` which  I than converted jvm from 1.6 to 1.8 now there is an error `Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option ` I am not getting a solution for this

Comment: You need `kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "1.8" }` in the `android` block in `build.gradle`.

Comment: Sir, I used what you said, now when I play the app it is showing an warning `viewmodelprovider deprecated ` and also the screen is blank

Comment: You're describing code that you haven't posted, so I don't know what's wrong. Your code above doesn't use ViewModelProvider. I also noticed that you were trying to use `by viewModels` inside the `onCreateView` method. You can only use property delegates at the property declaration, not for local variables.

Comment: I know I haven't used ViewModelProviders but It is showing a warning and for the second statement are you saying that I would use `lateint` in declaring `by viewmodels`

Comment: Should I send you the code

Comment: You can edit your question or start a new one. Read the language docs about property delegates to understand how it works. It is not `lateinit`.

Answer (score 11):

Since you are using a fragment in addition `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1"` adding this to your `build.gradle`
`implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"`

**Usage in Fragment**

```
// Get a reference to the ViewModel scoped to this Fragment
val viewModel by viewModels<MyViewModel>()

// Get a reference to the ViewModel scoped to its Activity
val viewModel by activityViewModels<MyViewModel>()
```

Answer (score 0):

First add the the following dependencies to use viewModels(), (latest version)

```
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```

Then you can use in your fragment

```
private val yourViewModel: YourViewModel by viewModels { // scope is this fragment      
 YourViewModelFactory(YourRepository(YourItemDatabase.invoke(requireContext())))
}
```

Or

```
private val yourViewModel: YourViewModel by activityViewModels()// scope is it's activity
```