# ViewModel initialization using "viewModels()" vs "ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel::class.java)" in Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, fragment, viewmodel

We can initialize viewModel either by

```
private val viewModel: XViewModel by viewModels()
```

or

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(XViewModel::class.java)
```

in a Fragment.

I want to know if

```
private val viewModel: XViewModel by viewModels()
```

can be used in an Activity as well.

[image: I declared my viewModel and got error]

Over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60528425/how-to-implement-by-viewmodels), I realized is related to navigation and fragment.

Comment: It has nothing to do with navigation. It is available for AppCompatActivitities. Do you simply need to import it?

Comment: Add import path Activity files and dependencies project.

Comment: @AmeerAmjed could you help me with what dependency I've to add?

Comment: @Tenfour04, as you can see I'm using ''' AppCompatActivity'''

Comment: Yes, that’s why I’m asking if you’re just missing an import. I think it’s provided in the same Jetpack dependency as the one for fragments so I wouldn’t expect you to need to do anything there if you already have it working in a fragment.

Comment: ```import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels```  This is where I got it from in the case of fragment but I can't tell the path for activity

Answer (score 1):

You are missing this import in your `Activity`:

```
import androidx.activity.viewModels
```